# How to get the first image gallery of a product in woocommerce in a loop

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic, gallery

I want to display a product with a product image and when visitor hovers over that image, it will change to the first image from the product gallery. I am using this code to display the image gallery, but it displays all the images from product gallery. I just want the 1 image.

```
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```

Anybody know how to resolve this problem? Really appreciate any ideas.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the product thumbnail (I'm assuming you have this), what you need is a list (array) of the product images - WooCommerce has such methods, eg  `$product->get_gallery_attachment_ids()`.

You can grab the first ID in the array and use it to fetch the single image using [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), or [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url), etc., then use that as an alternate source for the main (thumbnail) image.

Incidentally, the `woocommerce_product_thumbnails` call is outputting markup that you probably don't want to use. You'll need to either discard this or unhook functions from it to get the output you want.

Comment: My problem is, I dont know how to get the grab first image from gallery. I am using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778288/get-woocommerce-product-gallery-image-caption but still get all images from gallery.

Comment: Instead of using `foreach` in that code, you need to just get the first URL like `wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_ids[0], 'large')`.

Comment: Thank you. With a small modification, the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**2018 Update:** Need to use `get_gallery_image_ids();` instead. Then use `wp_get_attachment_url()` with the first ID in the array returned.

```
$product->get_gallery_image_ids();
```